# How to deploy new and changed files only via FTP

Tags: ftp, deployment, automation

I'm working for a company who in some circumstances HAVE to deploy php web applications via FTP. I'm in the process of automating the deployment process and need to write a script to FTP the files to the staging and production environments.

Requirements:

1. Should only transfer new or changed files to the remote server

Restrictions:

1. No shell access of any kind on the remote environments
2. Not able to use rsync
3. Only FTP available

My question: Is there any FTP based utility I can employ that fulfils these requirements rather than write my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you control the client, you could use FTPFS on the client, then rsync the local directory to the apparently-local-but-really-mounted-via FTPFS directory.

I understand that FTPFS is now part of [LUFS](http://lufs.sourceforge.net/).

**Edit**: I'd love to link to a tutorial, but I normally just start with the project wiki, and something seems to be up with sourceforge right now.  CurlFTPFS, which seems to be based on cURL and FUSE, [can be found here](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/), and the mounting/unmounting there seems to be as simple as:

```
$ mkdir sunet
$ curlftpfs ftp://ftp.sunet.se/ sunet/
$ cd sunet/
$ ls -l
total 0
Dr-xr-xr-x   3 root root        96 Feb 23  2004 bin
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root        72 Mar  2  2004 dev
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root        48 Feb 23  2004 etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root       120 Feb 23  2004 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 622187310 Mar 11 06:13 ls-lR
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  76389037 Mar 11 06:15 ls-lR.gz
drwxrwxr-x  37 root root      1272 Feb 27 14:17 pub
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root root        72 Feb 23  2004 usr
$ cd ..
$ fusermount -u sunet/
```

Comment: Thanks - Do you have any links to a good tutorial?

Comment: In the end I decided to go with lftp - the mirror mode was failry trivial to implement. However I also followed your instructions and gave this a try. It works really well to - so am choosing this as answer.

Comment: Glad it was helpful and of interest, and above all that you have something in place that works for you!

Answer (score 2):

We use ant for scripting and automation. The ant FTP task has a 'depends' param that transfers only new or changed files http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of ncftp to sync a directory to the server. You could go as far as to drop that into capistrano (override :deploy and run the ncftp command once you have  checked out the version you want to deploy).